# Differences between Function that returns a string and read only string property

Tags: vb.net, methods, properties

Both methods below give the same result, what is the reason you would use one of the other.
I'm struggling to figure out what the subtle differences are between using a String Function over using a Read Only Property.

### Method 1

```
Public Function GetUserName() as String 
   Return "foobar"
End Function
```

### Method 2

```
Public ReadOnly Property UserName() as String 
   Get
      Return "foobar"
   End Get
End Property
```

Comment: It's about encapsulation: properties expose data while methods expose logic. It all boils down to the expectations of the caller. A property should return the data and hence run quickly and without side-effects. A method involves computation and may have side-effects inside the object and/or a longer running time.

Comment: WeSt: Thank you I did search the site before however I did not see that question in my results. Could you make your second comment a Answer please so I can mark it.
You explained it well.

Comment: Please upvote the original question and/or answer rather than rewarding me the answer :)

Comment: I will do once I can,I did read the other post just didn't quite understand it still until I read your comment. I preferred your wording on the matter made allot more sense to me. Thank you for the help.